# Kivy: I want to change an attribute (e.g. text) of a widget by means of another widget (e.g. button) on click

Tags: python, kivy

I am totally new to Kivy and want to make a transition of a screenmanager from one screen to another one. I cannot figure out though how I can access the attribute of the screenmanager inside the on_press method of a button.

Here is my Code so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class ScreenButton(Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        self.text = "Press Me!"

    def on_press(self, *args):
        sm.current = 'secondscreen'

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.transition = FadeTransition()

        sc1 = Screen(name='firstscreen')
        sc1.add_widget(ScreenButton())

        sc2 = Screen(name='secondscreen')
        sc2.add_widget(Label(text='Another screen!'))

        sm.add_widget(sc1)
        sm.add_widget(sc2)

        return sm

MainApp().run()
```

I understand, that this code does not work since sm is not defined inside the method of the button. But how do I get acces to a specific widget inside a class definition of a button for example? Or is there a way more elegant way to setup a communication between widgets to change their conditions via each other?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also pass sm (ScreenManager) as a kwarg (see the ###). This way you can reuse the ScreenButton and don't have to use a global.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class ScreenButton(Button):

   def __init__(self, **kwargs): ###
       super(ScreenButton, self).__init__()

       self.manager = kwargs.pop('manager', None) ### 
       self.text = "Press Me!"

   def on_press(self, *args):

       self.manager.current = 'secondscreen' ###


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager()

        sm.transition = FadeTransition()

        sc1 = Screen(name='firstscreen')
        sc1.add_widget(ScreenButton(manager=sm)) ###

        sc2 = Screen(name='secondscreen')
        sc2.add_widget(Label(text='Another screen!'))

        sm.add_widget(sc1)
        sm.add_widget(sc2)

        return sm

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: This works! What I dont understand is that by this line:
self.manager = kwargs.pop('manager', None)
I am creating another anager inside the button class right?
How come, that by chaning the state of self.manager, I am also changing the state of sm which is defined outside?
Greetings

Comment: because self.manager IS sm (or at least is a reference too it). 'kwargs.pop('manager', None)' is like saying there is a keyword called "manager" that might be passed into this class, if it is, then self.manager refers to that (and if not, self.manager has a value of None). In this case when you create ScreenButton(manager=sm) you are passing the "value" of sm to the keyword manager which becomes self.manager... did that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in your example, is to make `sm` global:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class ScreenButton(Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScreenButton, self).__init__()
        self.text = "Press Me!"

    def on_press(self, *args):
        sm.current = 'secondscreen'


sm = ScreenManager()


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.transition = FadeTransition()

        sc1 = Screen(name='firstscreen')
        sc1.add_widget(ScreenButton())

        sc2 = Screen(name='secondscreen')
        sc2.add_widget(Label(text='Another screen!'))

        sm.add_widget(sc1)
        sm.add_widget(sc2)

        return sm

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,  I have a completely different solution, and it requires a lot less effort. You will need 2 files, main.py and screens.kv

Here is main.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

And screens.kv:

```
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager

<Manager>
    transition: sm.FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>
    name: 'First'
    GridLayout:
        Label:
            text: "First Screen"
        Button:
            text: "Press Me!"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Second'

<SecondScreen>
    name: 'Second'
    GridLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Second Screen"
        Button:
            text: "Press Here!"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'First'
```

Hope This Helps.

Comment: Using a .kv file is easier,  because as your code gets more complex, it will be easier to keep all of your widgets in order.  Also in a .py file you have to manually add all of your widgets,  where as in a kv file you need only reference them.  You can find everything you need at https://kivy.org/docs